# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isstr'

Tags: python, bots, irc

I am trying to make python module for jenni/phenny irc bot.

This is part of my code

```
def bp(jenni, input):
    try: 
        text = input.group(2).encode('utf-8').split()
    except: 
        jenni.reply("Please use correct syntax '.bp id weapons 7'. Available for weapons and food only")
    if text[0].isstr() and text[1].isstr() and text[2].isdigit() and len(text) == 3 and text[1] == ('weapons' or 'food'):
        url = 'http://someAPIurl/%s/%s/%s/1.xml?key=%s' % (text[0], text[1], text[2], key)
```

If the input is already a `str` why would I be getting this error?

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isstr'

Comment: If it's a `str` then you know it's `isstr`, you don't need a method for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says; `str` has no method `isstr()`.

If you want to make sure that it's only letter(s), use `.isalpha()`.

Example:

```
>>> '0'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'a'.isalpha()
True
>>> 'aa'.isalpha()
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) and either `basestring` for Python 2.x and `str` or `unicode` for Python 3.x:

```
isinstance(your_string, basestring)
```

That is the question that you originally asked but is probably not what you meant.  Your sample code suggests that you really want to know how to check to see if a string is either alphabetic or alphanumeric.  For that you want to use the [`isalpha`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) or [`isalnum`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) string methods.

> #### str.isalpha()
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are
>   alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

You may also want to consider refactoring your code to make it a bit easier to read and maintain.  Maybe something like this:

```
API_URL = 'http://someAPIurl/%s/%s/%s/1.xml?key=%s'
KIND_CHOICES = ('weapon', 'food')

def bp(jenni, input):
    try:
        cmd, kind, index = input.group(2).encode('utf-8').split()
        # Assigning to 3 variables lets you skip the len() == 3 check
        # and can make the use of each argument more obvious than text[1]
    except:
        jenni.reply("Please use correct syntax '.bp id weapons 7'. Available for weapons and food only")
    if cmd.isalpha() and kind in KIND_CHOICES and index.isdigit():
        url = API_URL % (cmd, kind, index, key)  # is key a global?
    # ...
```

Comment: This will only check if the *type* is a string. The OP wants to check the *contents* of his string.

Comment: @eric Please feel free to edit a question if you feel that you can make it easier for people to answer it correctly.  Editing questions can help improve the quality of answers a great deal.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But editing a question should do things like fixing spelling, adding documentation, and clarifying things that are not explained. But if you've provided an incorrect answer, it's not up to someone else to correct it.

Comment: Ian's answer makes sense in that input isn't guaranteed to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: - `text[0].isalpha()`..

There is no such method `isstr()` for string..

And in place of `text[1] == ('weapons' or 'food')`, you should use `in` operator..

```
if (text[1] in ('weapons', 'food')) {
}
```